# Not creating valid JSON using Gson in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm converting a list object into JSON object using GSON library. But, its not creating properly.

```
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("id", userId);
query.setCacheable(true);
List<?> results = query.list();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(results);
System.out.println("JSON "+json);
```

### Output

```
[{"id":2,"uid":"123456","widgetModelList":"[{\"name\":\"Icon Feedback\",\"id\":\"7\"},{\"name\":\"My Projects\",\"id\":\"8\"}]","widgetGalleryList":"[{\"name\":\"Icon Feedback\",\"id\":\"7\"},{\"name\":\"My Projects\",\"id\":\"8\"}]","userId":"{\"Id\":\"123456\"}","defaultWidget":"{\"name\":\"Another New Tasks\",\"icon\":\"icon_task\",\"id\":\"4\"}","others":"{\"role\":\"STAFF\",\"todoInDashboard\":true,\"templateURL\":\"views\\/tasks.html\"}"}]
```

If we observe carefully, its appending " for values, example "userId":"{\"Id\":\"123456\"}".. This should be like "userId":{"Id":"123456"}.. What should be done? I can use JSONObject library, but is it not possible using GSON library?  Any ideas

Comment: What's the structure of your list elements? I guess the problematic parts are already strings there.

Comment: @Henry Everything is stored as part of varchar in DB

Comment: i tried to use tool to view the json and it is valid , you need to ask the format of the json for example  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

Comment: @Ran Ita a valid JSON. but the problem is for the values, its appending "" extra which should not be there for a JSON object

Comment: @ran , its still creating extra " for the values

Comment: sorry i didn't tried it myself but this is the direction for your answer , i had only similar problem

Comment: also you can search for jackson

Comment: @ran I can do it with JsonObject of org.json, but it will take a lot of steps, where we need to construct the final json object.

Comment: It seems that the value for userId is a string equal to {"Id":"123456"} (I did not quote the string on purpose). In this case, the JSON is correct, because the string values are reported between quotes, and the quotes in the string need to be escaped.

Comment: @maxvv, yeah but I don't want those values as strings because when I send the final JSON object to UI, they will have problem in parsing.